# How to delete google cloud project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google

I can't delete existing google cloud projects. When I click delete project in administration panel, nothing happens. No errors, no notifications.

Comment: I think I've solved may problem. First, I restarted my computer, then I deleted project from cloud shell using delete command.

Comment: Why don't you post it as an answer for others who may have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the project from the developers console does in fact do something, and relevant information can be found on the “shutting down” project [page](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en&ref_topic=6158848). 
In short: Shutting down a project in the console releases all resources used within the project. Only project owners can shut down or restore projects.

To shut down a project:

Go to the Cloud Platform Console.
Open the console menu  Gallery Menu  on the top left and select IAM & Admin, then select All projects.
Find the name or project ID of the project you want to shut down, then click DELETE PROJECT. A confirmation screen describing what will happen appears.
To confirm, enter your project ID and click Shut down.
Shutting down a project stops all billing and traffic serving, shuts down any Google Cloud Platform App Engine applications, and terminates all Compute Engine instances. All project data associated with Google Cloud and Google APIs services becomes inaccessible.

After a 7-day waiting period, the project and associated data are permanently deleted from the console.

Note that after the 7-day waiting period ends, the time it takes to completely delete a project may vary. For example, if a project has billing set up, it might not be completely deleted until the current billing cycle ends, you receive the next bill, and your account is successfully charged. Additionally, the number and types of services in use may also affect when the system permanently deletes a project.